# Angular 2 Navigate to home page on browser back,refresh button clicks

Tags: angular

I tried to redirect to home page on browser back and refresh buttons clicks.
I dis the change in app.component.ts and the code is as follows:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    landingUrl: string = "/";

    constructor(private location: PlatformLocation, private router: Router) {

        //redirect on back button.
        location.onPopState(() => {
            window.location.href = this.landingUrl;
        });

        //redirect on refresh button.
        if (window.location.pathname != "/") {
            window.location.href = this.landingUrl;
        }

    }
}
```

This has two issues

1. I am using PlatformLocation which is not recommended to use
2. To handle the refresh button Im using window.location.pathname != "/"

Can I improve this further?

Comment: Did I get it correctly? You're trying to redirect to your homepage when user hit the `backward` button, or `refresh` button

Comment: Yes you are correct!

Comment: Why are you doing this? Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve? Sounds like a typical [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @sabithpocker As I have mentioned above, I need to redirect user to home page on browser Refresh and Back button.

Comment: Redirect user from which page to home page? You are doing it in app component which is probably the home page? Also do you want this behavior on all routes or only certain routes? **Why** do you need this on certain routes? Is this a redirect inside angular app or are you redirecting to a non-angular home page? Can you add how your app is routed and which routes should do this behavior?

Comment: There are a lot of options like Guards and skipLocationChange for most scenarios, we can suggest one only if you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve. Did yoou read [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @sabithpocker In certain pages we have used emitters and on refresh and back button clicks we will not have data for those pages.
So we are planning to redirect to home page on those actions across all routes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
window.location.href = this.landingUrl;
```

use

```
this.router.navigate([this.landingUrl]);
```

Comment: `this.router.navigate([this.landingUrl]);` this is taking me to route i want and then suddenly redirects to origination page which is in history of browser